# I am not able get destination city in collect rate method

Tags: checkout, shipping, shipping-methods

I am trying to get Destination City in Collect rate Method of Magento 2

But its blank,

```
/**
 * Collect and get rates
 *
 * @param RateRequest $request
 * @return Result|bool|null
 */
public function collectRates(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest $request)
{
    if ($request->getDestCity()) {
        echo $request->getDestCity();
    }
}
```

Please Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Magento by default does not include city field in rate request, So you should to rewrite EstimateAddressInterface and add city field.